# increase value of row and update this value in the SQL database when consulted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When i read a value from the database, increase them by 1 and update the row it runs 12-13 times. Is there any logic i'm missing?

this is the current function:

```
    function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {
        $link = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM order_numbers WHERE id=1";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $order_id_db_ideal = $row["valueorder"];

$prefix = 'ID';
    $new_order_id = $prefix . $jaar . $order_id_db_ideal;

     $sql_update = "UPDATE order_numbers SET valueorder = valueorder + 1 WHERE id = 1";
     mysqli_query($link, $sql_update);


        return $new_order_id;
    }
```

Comment: it isn't clear what is happening here.  after reading it three times, i wonder _do you need to create a **primary key auto_increment** so you have a unique order id?_.  Also, please note that `$sql_update = "UPDATE order_numbers SET ideal=ideal+1 WHERE id=1";` will only ever update ONE row (where the id = 1).

Comment: This seems like an incredibly strange and unlikely thing to want to do

Comment: i know i only updates 1 row but the value of ideal is always increasing with 12, when i run this sql statement i think it runs 12 times, that's the problem

Comment: The SQL query itself doesn't run 12 times, you are probably calling the "change_woocommerce_order_number" function inside a loop or similar.

Comment: @Colandus you're right. He needs to check if the update function is being called in some loop or not

Comment: It's called trough: add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );

Do you have any option how i can increase by one?

Comment: i need to run a function after the payment is completed in woocommerce but it still not works.. and i can't find the solution,